# Convert List<List<string>> to Dictionary C#

Tags: c#, list

I have two List:

```
var listA = new List<List<int>> {
    new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
    new List<int> { 4, 5, 6, 7 },
    new List<int> { 6, 7, 8, 9 }
};

var listB = new List<string> { "number1", "number2", "number3", "number4" };
```

How to convert them to dictionary with listA is value, listB is key?

Comment: What language is this?  Please update your tags.

Comment: @StephenNewell updated

Comment: whats the expected output? and what you want the value for key "number4" as listB has 4 element and listA has 3 child list.?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ToDictionary` method as following:

```
var listA = new List<List<int>> {
    new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
    new List<int> { 4, 5, 6, 7 },
    new List<int> { 6, 7, 8, 9 }
};

var listB = new List<string> { "number1", "number2", "number3", "number4" };

var dic = listB.Select((k, i) => new { key = k, value = listA[i] })
          .ToDictionary(x => x.key, x => x.value);

//now, dic["number1"] is List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
```

Comment: you can get error, as listB has 4 element and listA has 3, so in above code you will get error.

Comment: @DeepakSharma I think it is just a sample to show what which is need